# Using GET for the values of two text inputs

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having some difficulty getting the values of two text inputs:

```
<form action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="q1">
<input type="text" name="q2" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

This is the search.php page:

```
$q1 = @$_GET['q1'];
$q2 = @$_GET['q2'];

if(isset($q1) && isset($q2)) {
$var= "$q1, $q2";
}

if(isset($q1) && empty($q2)) {
$var= "$q1";
}
```

When both `q1` and `q2` are filled out and sent, it works perfectly. However, when only the `q1` input is filled out and sent (leaving `q2` blank), it still creates `$var` using the the first if-statement -- `if(isset($q1) && isset($q2)` -- instead of the second one -- `if(isset($q1) && empty($q2)`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Suppressing errors (or in this case, warnings) with @ is generally a performance killer. Try checking if the value in `$_GET` `isset()` before assigning it to `$q1` or `$q2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting `$q1` and `$q2` so `isset($q1)` and `isset($q2)` will always return true. Try

```
if(isset($_GET['q1']) && isset($_GET['q2'])) {
```

Or test for an empty value:

```
if(empty($q1) && empty($q2)) {
```

Answer (score 4):

$q2 is set even if they don't enter any value. It's a valid form field (although containing an empty string).

Answer (score 2):

You're setting both $q1 and $q2 when you do the assignment:

```
$q1 = @$_GET['q1'];
$q2 = @$_GET['q2'];
```

In the case when the user didn't fill out the second field, $q2 just gets set to the empty string.

A string being empty is not the same as a string being null.

Take a look at this page about isset from the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($q1 != '' && $q2 != '') {
    $var = "$q1, $q2";
} elseif($q1 != '') {
    $var = "$q1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are they both being passed along - but not filled? I'm thinking a conditional more like:

```
!empty($_GET['q1']) && ($_GET['q1'] != '')
```

Some combination of that should help. I imagine q1 & q2 are being sent whether or not they're being used.